# Integer programming model not working

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have to formulate an Integer programming model for the following using XPRESS;

There are 10 items that need to assigned to 2 categories, A and B. Each item has a weight and 30 % of the weight is allocated to A and the remaining 70% to B.The objective is t minimize the difference between the items assigned to A and B.

The model i've come up with runs, but assigns all items to both stores(outputs a list of A and B which are equal to 1 for i=1..10) and gives an objective value of zero. Can i please get a hint on what i've done wrong?

This is my code:

```
MODEL abc
USES "mmxprs"
DECLARATIONS
U : integer
Item = 1..10
Weight: array(Item) OF REAL
A,B: array(Item) OF MPVAR 
END-DECLARATIONS
Weight :: [12,7,16,10,11,23,21,13,19,14]
SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*A(i)+ SUM(j in Item)Weight(j)*B(j)>= 0.3*(SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)+ SUM(j in Item)Weight(j))
SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*(1-A(i))+ SUM(j in Item)Weight(j)*(1-B(j)) <= 0.7*(SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)+ SUM(j in Item)Weight(j))
! All variables are 0/1
forall(i in Item) A(i) is_binary  
forall(i in Item) B(i) is_binary  
Item_a:= SUM(i in Item) getsize(A(i))
Item_b:= SUM(i in Item) getsize(B(i))
abc:=Item_a >= 0
cgc:=Item_b >= 0
Objective:= U
hgfg:=Item_a-Item_b <= U
ushs:=Item_b-Item_a <= U
minimize (Objective)
! Print out the solution
writeln("Solution: ", getobjval)
forall(i in Item)  writeln(" A(", i, "): ", getsol(A(i)), "B(", i, "): ", getsol(B(i)))
END-MODEL
```

Comment: You need constraints that say that, for each i, A(i) + B(i) = 1.  (i.e. each item is assigned to exactly one of the two categories.)

Comment: Thanks, it works but the solution is still zero..

Comment: Which items are placed in category A?

Comment: the items whose weight is 30% of the total

Comment: Also, the model assigns items 4-9  to A and 1,2,3,10 to B which doesn't satisfy the weight constraint.

Comment: Take the given solution and plug it in to the weight constraints you have written and you will find that the constraints are satisfied.  (Hint:  Those constraints are where your problem is (as well as Doug's first comment))

Comment: I can't figure it out, is it the RHS or the LHS the problem is in?

Comment: Well, in one RHS, you added up the sum of the weights *twice* and multiply the doubled sum by 0.3 and in another RHS, you took *two* times the sum of the weights and multiplied by 0.7.

Comment: Thanks,  does this look right: 
SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*A(i)+ SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*B(i)>= 0.3*(SUM(i in Item)Weight(i))
SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*(1-A(i))+ SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*(1-B(i)) <= 0.7*(SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)) But with this, i get zero for all A and B

Comment: Ignore previous comment. I've tried the following which works:FORALL(i in Item) DO
a(i):= 0.3*A(i)+ 0.7*B(i) <= Weight(i)
END-DO Is this right? The solution is still zero though..

Comment: Nope, those constraints won't help you.  Since A(i) and B(i) are binary variables, 0.3*A(i) + 0.7*B(i) <= 0.3+0.7 = 1 < weight(i) for all the weights in your list.

Comment: How about this?                                                                                     SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*A(i)>= 0.3*(SUM(i in Item)Weight(i))
SUM(i in Item)Weight(i)*(B(i)) <= 0.7*(SUM(i in Item)Weight(i))

Comment: It assigns all items to A though

Comment: In the second constraint, it should be ">= 0.7", not "<= 0.7"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33887/discussion-between-doug-chatham-and-sophie).